# Read files from database and put it into my Combo box over HTML page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I try to add my files into `DropDownList`, all my files with the relevant property already return by the controller:

```
// GET: /WebMail/
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var fileNameList = db.Captures.ToList().Where(x => x.robotFamily == "WebMail");
    //return View(db.Captures.ToList().Where(x => x.robotFamily == "WebMail"));
    ViewBag.Files = fileNameList;
    return View();
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<AutomationCapturesMVC.Models.Capture>

@{
    //ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th style="font-size: 20px">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.fileName) 
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
        @Html.DropDownList("Id", (IEnumerable<AutomationCapturesMVC.Models.Capture>)ViewBag.Files, new { id = "WebMail", @class = "btn dropdown-toggle" })

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size: 15px">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.fileName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("File Details", "Details", new { id = item.id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

this is my page error:

http://s21.postimg.org/983eokpfq/1231231313.jpg

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

In controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var fileNames = GetDatabaseFileNames();
    var fileNameList = fileNames.Select(d => new SelectListItem { Text = d.FileName, Value = d.FileName.ToString() }).ToList();
    ViewBag.Files = fileNameList;
    return View();
}
```

In View

```
@Html.DropDownList("DatabaseFiles", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Files, new { id = "DatabaseFiles", @class = "btn dropdown-toggle" })
```

Comment: This is my controller:
            return View(db.mbjects.ToList().Where(x => x.files == "test")); in my controller i am return all the relevant files, can i use this ?

Comment: Can you explain ? (i am new with ASP.NET)

Comment: You have to modify your controller.

Comment: Check the dropdown syntax, `@Html.DropDownList("DatabaseFiles", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Files`

Comment: New error: Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'WhereListIterator`1[AutomationCapturesMVC.Models.Capture]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]'

Comment: Because in ViewBag there is an Enumerable SelectListItems are present not of type Models.Capture. Hope it is clear for u now.

Comment: Sorry but not clear (i am new developer), can you show me my mistake on order to learn ?

Comment: As per your code, in the controller it is `var fileNameList = db.Captures.ToList().Where(x => x.robotFamily == "WebMail");ViewBag.Files = fileNameList;` which means ViewBag.Files is of a List Type. But in the View the code is `@Html.DropDownList("Id", (IEnumerable<AutomationCapturesMVC.Models.Capture>)ViewBag.Files, new { id = "WebMail", @class = "btn dropdown-toggle" })` which means here it is expecting ViewBag.Files of type `AutomationCapturesMVC.Models.Capture` but from Controller it is of type `List`

Comment: I have changed IEnumerable<AutomationCapturesMVC.Models.Capture> to List<AutomationCapturesMVC.Models.Capture> and it still not working

Comment: Still wrong, Please refer my answer, you have to put `(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Files`

Comment: I have changed my controller and removed the "ToList()" and changed to IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Files and still error

Comment: Also another error: "class" is a reserved word and cannot be used in implicit expressions.  An explicit expression ("@()") must be used.